# randomnumber javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm working for a client and I need to generate a coupon number on the fly. I found a javascript that works a charm in generating a random number. The problem is that I need to input the random number that's generated into another field - capture it somehow. My javascript knowledge is limited. Any suggestion or help is greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function randomnumber() {
document.forms[0].randomnumber.value=(Math.round(Math.random()*9999999999999999+1));
}
onload=randomnumber

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input id="randomnumber"type="text" name="randomnumber" readonly>
</form>
```

Comment: it's hard to tell what you're asking - do you need to use this same random number in another place on your page?

Comment: jbabey- Yes, exactly. Ultimately I need to get that number that is generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to store the random number to use in multiple places:

```
function getRandomNumber() {
    return Math.round(Math.random()*9999999999999999+1);
};

var randomNumber = getRandomNumber();

document.getElementById('randomnumber').value = randomNumber;

// do whatever else you want with the randomNumber variable
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use document.getElementById to retrieve the field.

```
function randomNumber() {
    document.getElementById('randomnumber').value =
        (Math.round(Math.random()*9999999999999999+1));
}
randomNumber();
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RNdYp/1/)

Comment: Thank you!
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
function randomnumber() {
document.forms[0].randomnumber.value=(Math.round(Math.random()*9999999999999999+1));
document.getElementById("pfRandomNumber").value =(document.forms[0].randomnumber.value);
}
onload=randomnumber

</SCRIPT>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the function as a VAR, using a return.

```
function randomnumber() { 
var x =document.forms[0].randomnumber.value=(Math.round(Math.random()*9999999999999999+1)); 
return:x
} 

var coupon = randomnumber()
```

You can then use javascript to populate any html with you 'coupon' var.

Haven't tested this, and its not very tidy, but it should work.